# org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service

Tags: soap, service

My client java code fails to create a call to soap web service and fails with below exception.
same code works fine when pointing to lower environments.
Appreciate any help.
thanks

```
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initialize(ServiceImpl.java:162)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.&lt;init&gt;(ServiceImpl.java:128)
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.client.ProviderImpl$JBossWSServiceImpl.&lt;init&gt;(ProviderImpl.java:574)
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.client.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:258)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.&lt;init&gt;(Service.java:112)
at com.informatica.dis.ws.WSStandardizeORGPhone.&lt;init&gt;(WSStandardizeORGPhone.java:42)
at com.infa.compositeApi.idqMdm.client.IDQSOAPClient.&lt;init&gt;(IDQSOAPClient.java:37)
at com.infa.compositeApi.idqMdm.service.handler.IDQSOAPHandler.&lt;init&gt;(IDQSOAPHandler.java:48)
at com.infa.compositeApi.idqMdm.service.OrganizationService.&lt;init&gt;(OrganizationService.java:83)
```